# What Kernel is suitable for the following data for SVM classification?

Tags: classification, svm, binary, kernel

I have the following 2 class data, as shown below. [image: figure].

Its a hand crafted example using two ellipse equations. I want to know what might be a recommended kernel to be used with this problem if I want to use an SVM based binary classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Rbf (Radial basis function) kernel ([Wikipedia for rbf](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel)) is the most suited for this problem, as its contour plots are circles.

For instance,  this [blog](http://arun-aiml.blogspot.com.es/2017/07/kernel-svm-support-vector-machine.html?m=1) solves very similar problems using the same kernel.